# Query Go string into a jsonb argument for jsonb_set in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I am using Go and `"github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool"`.

One of the fields in my table has `json` and I need to update two keys in one query.

The first problem was to update several keys at once but I think it works fine now with a nested `jsonb_set`.

A bigger problem is how parameter substitution works in this case.

```
UPDATE my_table
    SET 
        first_column=$2,
        json_column = JSONB_SET(JSONB_SET(
                     json_column::jsonb, 
                    '{first_key_name}', 
                     $3,
                     true), 
                '{second_key_name}', 
                $4,
                true),
        updated_at  = now() at time zone 'utc'
    WHERE id=$1
```

This yields, however, the `invalid input syntax for type json` error. Adding either `to_jsonb()` or `::jsonb` around/after the parameters ($3, $4) didn't help.

Below is how the `pgx` library is used to pass the arguments to the query. Both key value are of `string` type.

```
err := pool.QueryRow(ctx, myQuery,
        id,
        first_column,
        first_key_value,
        second_key_value
    ).
        Scan(...)
```

After some experimenting, it seems that one way to make it work is to use `jsonb_build_array` and then get the 0-th item. That looks totally unreadable and I am almost sure there must be a simpler way to achieve this.

```
UPDATE my_table
    SET 
        first_column=$2,
        json_column = JSONB_SET(JSONB_SET(
                     json_column::jsonb, 
                    '{first_key_name}', 
                     jsonb_array_element(jsonb_build_array($3::text), 0), 
                     true), 
                '{second_key_name}', 
                jsonb_array_element(jsonb_build_array($4::text), 0),
                true),
        updated_at  = now() at time zone 'utc'
    WHERE id=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `||` operator here.
Initially lets say the record look like this:

```
{"a":"b","key2":"value2"}
```

After update

```
update dummy set j=j::jsonb||'{"a": "new_value"}
{"a":"new_value","key2":"value2"}
```

Remember it replaces top level keys if found otherwise create a new key. use jsonb_build_object to create json object on right side of || operator